# how to make the command get proper file path?

Tags: vim

There are two lines in my _vimrc file as under.

```
: cd  c:\workspace   # i want gvim run in my c:\workspace
nnoremap <F4> :exe ':silent !"c:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" %'<CR>
```

There is a file in  `c:\test\mytest.html`,if i move c:\test\mytest.html into c:\workspace, make the file to be `c:\workspace\mytest.html` ,when i open it with gvim ,in command mode ,inoput F4 ,it can call firefox to open the mytest.html correctly.

If i open the file  `c:\test\mytest.html` with gvim and input F4,it can call firefox but can not  properly open the file,gvim cannot get the right file path, how can i revise the map command to make the task done?

```
nnoremap <F4> :exe ':silent !"c:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" %'<CR>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
nnoremap <F4> :exe ':silent !"c:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" %:p'<CR>
```

And do read `:help filename-modifiers`.

Comment: And read `:help shellescape()` one you wonder why this won't work with files containing special characters.

Comment: Is there a reason for the construction `:exe ':foo'<CR>` instead of simply `:foo<CR>`?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of reinventing the wheel, have a look at the [open-browser.vim - Open URI with your favorite browser](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3133) plugin. It defines an `:OpenBrowser {uri}` command, and has many more useful features.