# can not find the file in my desktop

Tags: html, vim

There is a simple html file test.html in `C:\Documents and Settings\sanya\desktop`.
I can open it whith firefox and the music will play.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>    
<html>    
<body>    
<audio src="file:///C:/m1.mp3" controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay"></audio>    
</body>    
</html>
```

In my _vimrc file ,there is a map relationship between firefox and F4 key.

```
nnoremap <F4> :exe ':silent !"c:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" %:p'<CR>
```

When i open the test.html file with gvim ,and press F4 , got the message:

```
firefox cann't found the file in Firefox /C:/Documents  。
```

How can i revise something to press F4 in my gvim and make the music play?

When i open it with gvim ,

Comment: It looks like there's an issue with the spaces in the file path, notice how it cuts off at the first space after Documents. For the sake of testing, place `test.html` in a directory with no spaces in its path, something like `C:\test.html`, and try again.

If that works, you'll have to figure out how to place quotes around filename that gets sent to firefox from your remap. That might be as easy as putting quotes in. If that's the case, post back and I'll write an actual answer.

Comment: yes, as @esel mentioned make sure you escape whitespace in file path by using `\\` before each space.

Comment: You can also use `escape()` instead of escaping the spaces one by one:  `:exe 'silent !"' . escape('c:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe', ' ') . '" %:p'`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I already mentioned the need for proper escaping [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21180621/813602), and the same was even mentioned [in an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20944019/813602) to your question where you apparently got the mapping from.

```
:nnoremap <F4> :exe ':silent !"c:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"' shellescape(expand('%:p'), 1)<CR>
```

PS: The path to Firefox would better be passed through `shellescape()` instead of the manual escaping; I leave this as an exercise to you.

Comment: i have read the `:help  shellescape()`,do not know what the number  `1` in  shellescape(expand('%:p'), 1)  mean ,expand('%:p')  result in the current file name.

Comment: The help tells you this: For `:!`, more characters need to be escaped, the `1` configures that. For `system()`, you'd omit that or pass `0`.